# Cannot connect Java Mission Control to remote machine

Tags: java, jmx, java-mission-control

I am trying to connect JMC to my remote server.

Added the following flags to the the JVM:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7000 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Opened port 7000 in my firewall, but everytime I try to connect from JMC, I get the following error:

```
Could not connect to Prod : Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException]
```

Can't seem to get this working, I have tried to add another flag:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7000
```

But it did not help.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: It might help to add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<hostname reachable from client>

Answer (score 1):

The flags seem to be correct. Probably the issue is related to firewall. Have you tried without the firewall? If it still doesn't work, you can try the following:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.autodiscovery=true
```

and the connection will show up automatically in JMC, if you are on the same network.

Comment: Have tried without the firewall with no success. Regarding auto discovery, unfortunately I am not on the same network at all so I am not sure this can work..